# One instance of Message Driven Bean with JEE5

Tags: java, singleton, javabeans, java-ee-5

I would like to do something similar to @Singleton (or @Lock) to a MDB but it needs JEE6 or more. Is there any other way to do similar things with JEE5?

Thanks to all the reader!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found in the case of Stateless and MessageDriven Bean.

```
@PoolClass(value = org.jboss.ejb3.StrictMaxPool.class, maxSize = 1)
```

Obviously you can set the number that you want to maxSize propertie (but it seems to be a limit).